# How do I prepare a statement in mysql with a dynamic index column for sorting purposes?

Tags: mysql, sorting, prepared-statement

Is a statement like the following possible?  If not, do I need to rely upon the server side script (PHP) processing to generate a couniting index for sorting purposes?

```
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("SET @row_number := 0; SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS `idx`, vin, plugTime, unplugTime
        FROM plug_events
        WHERE asset = ?
        ORDER BY idx DESC
    ");
```

Here's what I resorted to (storing the resulting html output in an array called rows, then imploding the reversed array by empty spaces), but is it the only way?

```
<?php echo implode("",array_reverse($rows)); ?>
```

Comment: it makes no sense to enumerate on the SQL side if you are using PHP. Also, I don't understand the purpose of such "sorting". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Your query makes no sense - the rows enumeration is not definite (in most cases it will be enumerated by primary key value increasing but this is not a dogma).

Comment: The query returns rows in reverse order, I wanted to flip that,  array processing seemed most logical to solve this issue, albeit not as hoped but without performance penalty

Comment: Why not use window functions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number